# reversible modulo equation

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, cryptography

I came across an equation regarding some cryptography article that said for each $i$
$z_i= \mod( \lfloor(s_i*f)\rfloor+p_i, f)$ is reversible, i.e given $f, z,s$ we can get back $p$. My question is I doubt that this equation is invertible, but if at all this equation is invertible what makes it invertible, because there is a modulo operation involved and a flooring function  which are not one-one

Comment: Maybe the article means this: although the $p$ you get back may not be unique, the uniqueness does not matter, i.e., the $p$ you obtain is unique up to this modulo operation; and this is sufficient for the cryptography to work. This is my hunch.

Comment: But how do you get back `a' $p$

Comment: What are the ranges/domains of of your functions/variables? What is the **excact** statement of the claim in the article?

Comment: $f=8$,  $0\leq p_i\leq 255,~\forall~ i$, $0\leq s_i\leq 1$

Comment: Consider operations in $Z/fZ$ simply